# Download pdf file from binary string in Angular 7 typescript

Tags: typescript, angular7

I am using Angular 7, I am new to this. I need to upload pdf document, save it as binary string and download it has pdf when needed. 
I am able to save the pdf file as binary string in database, but I am unable to download the file as pdf, in few scenario I get only blank pdf file.

File upload code

```
onFileChange(event) {
   let reader = new FileReader();
   if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
      this.newDoc=reader.result;
      };
   }
}
```

I need help for downloading the available binary string to pdf file. I have below code, but it return empty pdf file

```
downloadPdf(){
   this.pdfString=this.projectsData[0].PDFFILE;
   const blob = new Blob([this.pdfString], { type: 'application/pdf' }); 
   const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   window.open(url); 
}
```

Comment: did you solve it ?